# Объявление массива переменной длины Python

Tags: python

Подскажите как объявить массив, размер которого будет зависит от цикла

Comment: А для чего это нужно? `items = []` не хватит вам?

Comment: В python нет массивов фиксированного размера. Если быть предельно точным, то и массивов нет.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, в numpy есть, еще есть стандартный модуль [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)

Comment: Уточните, в каждом проходе цикла вы хотите определять новый массив и его размер зависит, например, от номера цикла,  или в каждом проходе цикла вы хотите просто  изменять размерность одного и того-же массива?

Answer (score 1):

В Python массивы (а точнее, list или лист) не объявляются с размером.
Например, `items = []` изначально пустой, однако после выполнения программы его размер может быть и `len(items) = 5` или `len(items) = 10`.

Обратите внимание на [официальную документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list).

Comment: Так list - это как бы и не массив. Массив - это array  из модуля array или объект ndarray из Numpy.